# Local int vs Global int in C

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables

I read that:

> in C, local variables start with unknown value

and I decided to check it, that's what I did:

Three results of the same program: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPd2k.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7SEr.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNk2i.png).

**Question 1:** Why unknown value in 1, or why global `int` was 0 and local `int` was 1?

**Question 2:** Why local `unsigned int` with each new start was different?

**Question 3:** Is global/local `char` ' '? `char ch = ' '; // something like that`

**Question 4:** Why global and local start with different values (if they are not initialised)? For what?

Source code: (I used clang (v10.0.0) for compiling)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global_int;
unsigned int global_unsint;
char global_char;

int main()
{
  int local_int;
  unsigned int local_unsint;
  char local_char;

  printf ("Global int: %d \t unsigned_int: %u \t char: %c\n", global_int, global_unsint, global_char);
  printf ("Local int: %d \t unsigned_int: %u \t char: %c\n", local_int, local_unsint, local_char); 
}
```

Comment: Such a nice clear, concise set of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> local variables start with unknown value

Not entirely true. Local variables with *automatic storage duration* do; `static` variables are initialized at zero. As it happens, all the local variables in `main()` in your code snippet have automatic storage duration.

> Why unknown value it's 1, or why global int was 0 and local int was 1?

Global variables have static storage duration. This means they are implicitly initialized at zero on program startup.  Local variables with automatic storage duration have undefined values until they are explicitly initialized.

> Why local unsigned_int with each new start was different?

That's undefined behavior for you. All bets are off.

> Is global/local char was ' ' ?

No. The global `char` is implicitly initialized as `'\0'` on program startup; the local `char` has an undefined value.

> Why global and local start with different values (if they are not initialised)? For what?

Because of rules for initialization of objects with static storage duration and automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing uninitialized (or previously unassigned) variable invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://wiki.c2.com/?UndefinedBehavior).

Anything can happen; for example

- your compiler may produce an executable
- your executable may "run"
- running your executable may appear to work as expected
- the values printed may be reasoned for

or none of the above, depending on the phase of the moon, the compiler flags, what other programs are running on your computer at the same time, ..., ..., ...

Comment: that is, he simply pokes at which part of the memory and ...?

Comment: there may be no poking anywhere. As far as I can tell, the compiler itself may sing the national anthem of Honduras instead of producing an executable, or, idiomatically, there may be nasal daemons flying out the computer USB port.

Comment: In other words, any attempts at reasoning about undefined behavior are futile.

Comment: Accessing an uninitialized object is not universally undefined behavior. For example, an `unsigned char` that either does not have automatic storage duration or whose address is taken does not have padding bits, cannot have a trap representation, and does not trigger the special rule about an uninitialized object of automatic storage duration whose address has not been taken. It merely has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand what is going on you should know that most architectures use a stack on which the local, automatic variables are allocated. With each function called ("invoked"), some storage of the stack is used and upon each function return that storage is available again.

That means that the automatic variables of a function use stack space that has been used before (by another function) and because these variables are not initialized by the compiler or run-time system, they contain values from earlier function invocations. So for your function, their values are *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

`global_int`, `global_unsint`, `global_char` are the global variable. They will be located in the bss segment. The OS kernel will simply maps them to Copy-On-Write with pages of zero values for saving the paging processing on OS-side. That's why you always see the values of them are zero.

`local_int`, `unsigned int local_unsint`, `local_charq are the automatic variable. They will be located on stack segment of the main function. The values of them is not know exactly. They depends on memory location on the stack  that they were assigned in the run-time. So we can not trust the initialized values for automatic variable.

Comment: The reason zeros are seen in the `global*` objects is because the C standard says they are initialized to zero. The fact that some operating systems and compilers use a `bss` segment for them is merely one possible implementation. Further, the `local*` objects are not necessarily located on the stack. Optimization during compilation may produce other effects.